# how to align the simple text to vertically center of the page by using only HTML

Tags: html

i want the text Hello World to be in the center of the page

this is my code but not working:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
       body { text-align: center; }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<center>Hello world</center>
</body>
</html>
```

i dont want to use div tag

Comment: don't use <center>, it's deprecated

Comment: It is working  check this http://jsfiddle.net/waanK/
and `<center>` is deprecated tag btw it might be from it

Comment: @c_kick please help how to do it i am stuck from long time

Comment: @kidwon but its not center middle to page

Comment: just chane the `<center>` to `<span>`

Comment: which browser are you testing in?

Comment: I don't understand, it works in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/MU4dk/ (note: middle of the page = middle of the 'result' part in jsfiddle)

Comment: Here it is again, fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/MU4dk/embedded/result/

Comment: @c_kick it should be vertically centered to page

Comment: Try this @Goofy http://jsfiddle.net/enve/8MEwY/

Comment: @Goofy can I ask why you don't want to use a `<div>` tag? You could use a `<span` with the following style `style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;"`.

Comment: Ah, **vertical**.. you should mention that in your question :) see Enve's answer, and accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

**HTML**

```
<html style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <body style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <p>Hello world</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/enve/8MEwY/2/

Comment: can we acheive it without using a table?

Comment: Tables should not be used for page layouts. They should only be used to display data.

Comment: i agree with you but i want to do it by using only HTML

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
       body { text-align: center; margin-top:50%; }
    p{margin:auto;
       color:blue;}
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<p>Hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Goofy try with" margin-top:50% ". I test and worked in your demo!

Answer (score 0):

Aligning text to the center is easy, just use:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p style="text-align:center">Hello world</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this without the `<table>` solution, but I'm not sure if it will work when you add more styling to the page.

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      p  { 
           margin-top: 25%; 
           text-align: center; 
           color: blue; 
         }
   </style>
</head>
   <body>
       <p>Hello world</p> 
   </body>
</html>
```